# Why is my desk wet?

Tags: lateral-thinking, physics

A brewing cup of tea sits on my desk.
Full of water and milk
When I put the cup down I was very careful not to spill a drop
When I came back 2 minutes later, my desk was damp with hot tea.

Why???

> Hint: The tea is brewing. Tea bags are in the cup.

Comment: Someone clearly knocked your tea over. What a jerk!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Not really sure if this is a riddle as I have had it happen to me :P The tea absorbed up the teabag string and then dripped down the outside of the mug. It usually takes a little longer than 2 min though...

Comment: Capillary action ftw

Comment: Is it physically possible? If liquid enters the string because of capillary action, why would it be going to leave it? This would make a perpetuum mobile.

Comment: It leaves it because it becomes saturated and the end of the string that is not in the tea allows an escape.

Answer (score 0):

> The cup is made of paper, and the paper is thick enough so that the desk is only damp after two minutes and not drenched.